# passing an object as a parameter to a constructor of another class C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make a user interface class for display the weather forecast retrieve from an API, using a Nokia5110 LCD, but I'm getting an error when I try to pass a reference to an `Adafruit_PCD8544 Object` from the .ino to the constructor of the class.

Some help will be highly appreciated. The error i get:

> "error: no matching function for call to
> `Adafruit_PCD8544::Adafruit_PCD8544()`"

this is the main.ino file:

```
// Nokia 5110 LCD pinout connections to nodeMCU8266
#define CLK_PIN D1  // Serial clock out (SCLK)
#define DIN_PIN D2  // Serial data out (DIN)
#define DC_PIN  D5  // Data/Command select (D/C)
#define CS_PIN  D6  // lCD chip select (CS)
#define RST_PIN D4  // LCD reset (RST)

Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(CLK_PIN, DIN_PIN, DC_PIN, CS_PIN, RST_PIN);
UI_Nokia5110 UI(display);
```

this is the header file for the UI.h:

```
#ifndef UI_WEATHER_API_H
#define UI_WEATHER_API_H

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_PCD8544.h>

class UI_Nokia5110{
  private:
    Adafruit_PCD8544 display ;
  public:
    UI_Nokia5110(){}
    UI_Nokia5110(Adafruit_PCD8544 &display);
    
};
#endif
```

here, the implementation UI.cpp

```
#include "UI_Nokia5110.h"

UI_Nokia5110::UI_Nokia5110(Adafruit_PCD8544 &display){
  this->display = display;
}
```

Comment: Most likely `Adafruit_PCD8544` doesn't have default constructor, but since you don't assign the value inside of *initializer list* the compiler tries to instantiate it without parameters first, and only after that assigns the new value with the copy assignment operator.

Comment: Also you are doing copy, so there will be globally visible display and another instance will be inside of class (that is shadowing that global instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Members are initialized before the constructor body is executed. The constructor body is not the place to initialize members. If you do not provide an initializer, the member `display` will be default constructed. The error says `Adafruit_PCD8544` has no default constructor. Use the member initializer list:

```
UI_Nokia5110::UI_Nokia5110(Adafruit_PCD8544 &display) : display(display) {
    // nothing to be done here, members are already initialized
}
```

For more details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor